# mis comandos sqlite no guardan datos en la base de datos c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

tengo un formulario que es para crear usuario y guardarlos recibe solo 3 datos: usuario, contraseña y tipo de usuario, los primeros dos campos son de un textbox y el tipo de usuario de un combobox, verifico si se crearon mediante un DB Browser
[image: este es el formulario]

y aqui esta el codigo, y es donde no solo no guarda los datos sino que al mandarlos ya no me deja hacer clic en naday tengo que cerrarlo

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string user = nombreusuario.Text;
            string contraseña = contrausuario.Text;
            string tipouser = selectipousuario.SelectedItem.ToString();
            SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:/Users/Usuario/source/repos/POS/POS/tienda.s3db");
            conexion.Open();
            string crearusuario = @"INSERT INTO Usuarios (id_usuario, nombre_usuario, contra_usuario, tipo_usuario) VALUES(null,  @usuario,  @contraseña,  @tipoU)";
            SQLiteCommand comando = new SQLiteCommand(crearusuario, conexion);
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@usuario", user));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@contraseña", contraseña));
            comando.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@tipoU", tipouser));
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error" + error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por qué no utilizas Entity framework

Comment: bueno no se lo que es, yo estoy empezando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `insert` noto que defines la columna `id_usuario` pero a esta le asignas un valor de `null`, si es una columnas que actuali como `primary key`, no puede definirle ese valor, si la columnas es autoincremental no la defines, y sino lo es al lo sumo previamente debes ejecutar el

```
SELECT MAX(id_usuario) FROM Usuarios
```

asi obtienes el ultimo id registrado y le sumas uno para pasar ese valor como parametro

Comment: buen dato, gracias!

Comment: Esto que marco puede ser la causa por la cual no persiste ya que el insert deberia estar marcando un exceltion, pero me desconcierta que no comentaras que visualizas un mensaje de error en e MessageBox, tampoco entiendo porque mencionas que "no te deja hacer nada" cuando se ejecuta ese codigo, eso es raro, acaso usas Form MDI o similar, porque puede que el mensaje de error quede por detras de un form modal

Comment: a que te refieres con marco? y no, no vizualizo ningun mensaje de error y cuando digo que no me deja hacer nada es que por ejemplo, si la ventana no se cierra al guardar los datos deberia al menos poder hacer clic en los campos pero no se puede, utilizo un windows form, no se que es MDI

Comment: Por "marco" hago referencia donde estoy puntualizando en la respuesta que proporciono. 
Si pones un breakpoint en el codigo ya vas paso a paso ejecuta correctamente el ExecuteNonQuery() ? No salta al catch.

Comment: perdon, es que lei mal lo de marco, entendi otra cosa y no, extrañamente no salta el mensaje del catch

Comment: pero puede ir paso a paso en la ejecucion y llegar al ExecuteNonQuery() pasando esa linea a la siguiente? si lo haces usa `int rowafectadas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();` evaluando que valor recibes de la ejecucion

Comment: lo voy a intentar